# Change the background-color of alternate elements css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-float

I wanna change the color of alternate elements, but my code is not working. My code changes the color of the whole container element.

Can anyone please tell me where am I making mistake in the code?

```css
.pvt-msg-panel {
  height: 92vh;
  float: left;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
#pvt-messages-box {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 650px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.pvt-messages-box-item {
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.pvt-messages-box-item:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: green;
}
.pvt-messages-box-item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="pvt-msg-panel">
  <section id="pvt-messages-box">
    <span class="pvt-messages-box-item"><span><img src="images/avatar2.png"></span>message 1</span>
    <br>
    <span class="pvt-messages-box-item"><span><img src="images/avatar2.png"></span>message 2</span>
    <br>
    <span class="pvt-messages-box-item"><span><img src="images/avatar2.png"></span>message 3</span>
    <br>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using `first-child` selector, the `br` tags will try to pick up the `even` selector. Try using the `nth-of-type` selector and there you go:

```css
.pvt-msg-panel{
  height: 92vh;
  float: left;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
#pvt-messages-box{
  height: 50vh;
  width: 650px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.pvt-messages-box-item{
  padding:10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pvt-messages-box-item:nth-of-type(odd){
  background-color: green;
}
.pvt-messages-box-item:nth-of-type(even){
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="pvt-msg-panel">
    <section id="pvt-messages-box">
        <span class="pvt-messages-box-item"><span><img src="images/avatar2.png"></span>message 1</span><br>
        <span class="pvt-messages-box-item"><span><img src="images/avatar2.png"></span>message 2</span><br>
        <span class="pvt-messages-box-item"><span><img src="images/avatar2.png"></span>message 3</span><br>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

here you have [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/paqycmh9/3/). use `nth-of-type(odd)` for `span`

```
.pvt-messages-box-item:nth-of-type(odd){
  background-color: green;
}

.pvt-messages-box-item:nth-of-type(even){
  background-color: white;
}
```

:nth-child matches if the element is the specified child of its parent. The 
 element inside the div is causing the odd and even part of your selectors to fail since it makes both spans odd children (1st and 3rd) of its parent.

Answer (score 2):

OK I found your problem.

First I copy your code to my jet brain and looks like that.ok?

[image: code looks like]

If I change such code:

```
background-color: red;
```

and the background become totally red. So problem is here, why?

First the first childElement of section is not span.pvt-message-box-item:nth-child(1) but whitespace and the second is such element. The third is the same which is also whitespace between first span element and the second element, now if you want to change the background color alternatively you have use this kind resolution. Change the css odd and even with the actual number like replacing odd and even with 1/3/5, and result appears ok with your request:

[image: satisfy result]